# Multiprocessing stops working after two iterations

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a program that iterates over all the pictures in a given folder and returns a numerical value:

```
    for filename in os.listdir(image_directory):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                q = Queue()
                p = Process(target=analysis_main, args=(q,os.path.join(image_directory, filename), points_path, 
                              real_points_path,transform_path, inverse_path, lane,))
                p.start()
                dist = q.get()
                p.join()

            data.append([filename, dist])
```

Because some unwanted memory gets stored after one picture is analysed, I have to use
multiprocessing module which fixes the problem and the program runs fine, but only when I am not using queue and only printing the result I get from the analysis(dist). When I use queue the program only analyses two pictures and then stops, but it is not killed. 
I am fixing this problem for a while now and really don't know what else to do.

Comment: are you certain that the subprocess actually places anything on the queue?

Comment: Yes, because if I try to run it on folder with only two images works fine, problem arises when it gets to the third picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'classic' solution would be to have a timeout when you're waiting on the queue. In the following chunk of code, I'm using a 3-second timeout - but the number can be different, of course.

```
from queue import Empty 
for file in ...:

    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=analysis_main, args=(q, filename, ...))
    p.start()

    try:
        dist = q.get(True, 3)
        p.join()

        data.append([filename, dist])

    except Empty as e:
        print(f"didn't get anything for {filename}")
```

Now, you'll be able to identify or skip 'bad' files. This is a better design overall, as it also reduces the chances that your program hangs because of a bug in the processing function.